# Exceptions and validity checks relevance

Tags: exception, nullreferenceexception

I've been programming with a fellow partner at my new job and i watched him coding a new method.
this method received an object and he didn't checked for the parameter validity (!= null etc.)
when i asked him why? - he answered that its intended - "if for some bad reason there is a null object parameter (and it shouldn't) i want it to fail miserably and not swallow the error."

Do you agree with this? when should i do validity checks? and how deep should i go with them? i mean i can think of millions validity checks for most functions (not just null pointer validity)..

Comment: In my opinion, it depends what the method is for.  Internal subroutines for me are quite fragile and break easily, then leave error handling to the calling code; routines that are visible from outside are more robust and do all the parameter checking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the exception generated will be obtuse and difficult to debug without digging down into the code.

Or you could check for the case, and provide a nice exception message.

Given the following method signature:

```
public void DoStuff(MyObj obj);
```

***"DoStuff requires an instance of MyObj to function"***

is much nicer than

***"Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object"***